# Primary Key and Functional Depe

Tags: ms-access

I have a table below and I would like to get confirmation on one of the functional dependencies.

Taylor Johnson is the name of two twins who live in the same house.
Student ID is a unique ID and hence it is the candidate/primary key.

But Student ID doesn't functionally determine Student Name or does it? I don't think it does because knowing student ID wouldn't tell you which Taylor Johnson you are talking about. If that is the case, then I cannot say that my candidate/primary key (Student ID) functionally determines all other attributes in the table even though it is a unique key. Doesn't it then violate the definition of a primary key? Thanks for any insights in advance!

```
Student ID  Student Name    DOB         Street  City     State    Zip
1          Taylor Johnson   4/10/1988   Meadow   Raleigh    NC    27606
2          Taylor Johnson   4/10/1988   Meadow   Raleigh    NC    27606
3           Kim Blake       2/10/1998   Crescent Cary       NC    27512
```

Comment: Twins can't have identical names.  While it's conceptually possible to have 2 students in the same class with the same name (I went to school with 2 sets of kids with the same names who weren't related, so it *does* happen), it'd be a rarity that they had identical birthdays and live on the same street.  Worst case scenario, make house# a field.

Comment: Thanks so do you agree that in the case of two students with the same name and DOB that live at the same address, I cannot say that Student ID determines Student Name? In other words, there is no functional dependency. But in this case, would student ID still be the primary key even though two unique student IDs can have the same name, DOB, address and we cannot say that primary key determines other attributes in the table?

Comment: You would *have* to have some other uniquely identifying field, unless you expect the administrators to remember which is which, but the Student ID alone could be the primary key in either case.

Comment: StudentID would still be primary/foreign key for linking related records and that is really only what a primary/foreign is supposed to do. It should not have any meaning to users and users shouldn't even be aware of it, especially an autonumber PK. Just might need another attribute in order to select from combobox list. Maybe have to resort to birth city, birth mark, health issue, etc.

Comment: Now if you have a custom generated StudentNumber (akin to SSN), that would be different from StudentID PK/FK link. Some (I have) will use StudentNumber both as a PK/FK link and as data with meaning to users. However, since this is most likely a text type field, it will be a less efficient link.

Comment: Thanks. This helps!